# Edit an already styled dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm parsing a huge excel and some cell scenarios would be wrong and I'm parsing them using a "RedFlag" on a tuple for example:
("1 mm", "RedFlag") , ("10 mm", "Redflag"), ("0.5254", "GreenFlag")

I was able to use df styling to identify all tuples that has RedFlag and paint the background red.

But then I want to format this dataframe again to remove the RedFlags/GreenFlags leaving only the values of the tuple first index like "1mm", "10mm" and 0.5254.

It seems super simple but I can't seem to accomplish this, I end up either with a tuple colored dataframe or a the first index of tuple but no color formatting.

```
import pandas as pd
from config import start_logger
from conversions import parse_decimal_inch_4
import logging
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler


def parse_value(value, header):
    """
    Parse the given value based on the header logic.

    Parameters:
    - value (str): The value to parse.
    - header (str): The header containing the parsing logic.

    Returns:
    - str: The parsed value.
    """
    if "Decimal Inch - 4 Decimals" in header:
        # Parse to 4 decimals inches
        logging.info("Parsing ORIGINAL: %s", value)
        cell_result = parse_decimal_inch_4(value)
        logging.info("Parsed RESULT: %s", cell_result)
        return cell_result

        """    elif "mm - 2 Decimals" in header:
                breakpoint()
                # Remove 'mm' and parse to 2 decimals mm
                numeric_value = float(value.split()[0])  # Extract numeric part
                return "{:.2f}".format(numeric_value)"""
    else:
        # Default case: return the original value
        return value


def apply_style(value):
    if isinstance(value, tuple) and value[1] == "RedFlag":
        logging.info("RED FLAG")
        logging.info(value)
        logging.info(type(value))
        return "background-color: red"


def remove_tuples(value):
    try:
        filters = ["RedFlag", "GreenFlag"]
        if isinstance(value, tuple) and len(value) == 2:
            if value[1] in filters:
                return value[0]
        return value
    except Exception as exc:
        logging.error(
            "And Exception occurred while trying to apply styles and parse tuples %s",
            exc,
        )


def parse_excel(input_file, output_file):
    # Read data from Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)

    # Loop through each column
    for column in df.columns:
        # Apply the parsing function to each cell in the column
        df[column] = df.apply(lambda row: parse_value(row[column], column), axis=1)
    # Apply conditional styling to the DataFrame (background red) this works
    styler_df = df.style.applymap(apply_style)

    # ---- >>>>> HEre I want to be able to remove the tuples from the previously styled dataframe <<<<< ----    
    breakpoint()
    # Save the styled DataFrame to a new Excel file
    styler_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_logger()

    # Specify your input and output file names
    input_file_name = "Normalization Sample Data.xlsx"
    output_file_name = "Normalization Sample Data Output.xlsx"
    # Call the parsing function
    parse_excel(input_file_name, output_file_name)
```

Comment: you could create `minimal working code` with example data directly in code - so we could simply copy and test it.